# Kafka SSL setup Externalizing the Certificates in Certificate Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, apache-kafka, certificate, sasl

I have done a Kafka setup with SASL and SSL (SASL_SSL) by following the instructions from the Kafka documentation [here](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security_ssl)

The Setup works fine, as I am able to Produce and Consume the messages form the topics with corresponding Producer and Consumer Configurations.

I have two Questions for which I need help:

1. The SASL setup requires JAAS file configuration. As of now I have created a JAAS file on each broker node and have provided the JAAS file path to Kafka at startup time by using a property 'java.security.auth.login.config'. My Question is can I externalize this JAAS config ? My setup is on AWS and hence thinking if this JAAS config can be stored in EMR or S3 ? is it possible and in case it is, then how to achieve this ?
2. The SSL setup as per the documentation, I ended up creating a truststore (CARoot) and a keystore (signed cert and Key) in form of a Java Key Store and provided this info to Kafka through server.properties on each broker. I have been asked to look at using AWS KMS and Certificate manager to store the keys and certificates rather than Java Key Stores. Is this possible ?

Thanks and Regards,
AK